# Compiz does not work with proprietary nvidia driver

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, compiz, xorg

I have a ThinkPad T420 with an NVidia Quadro video card. It crashes constantly when I close this lid ([if you are curious..](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2049607)) and I suspect on a problem with nouveau drivers, so I installed the [proprietary NVidia drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

Howeer, when I install and use this driver, Compiz does not work. If I start a session with uses Compiz, no window manager/decorator is presented. I just can get Metacity working. Does anyone has any idea  about what may be causing this problem?

**Edit**: I am using the Nvidia Driver version 304.37. My video card is an Nvida Quadro NVS 4200M. `lspci` informs me that there is another controller in my machine: `VGA compatible controller, Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller`, which sounds strange to me (I actually do not understand a lot about hardware and would expect to have only one card in my notebook). My Ubuntu is 12.04.

Comment: Hi brandizzi. Welcome to askubuntu friend. I need to mention that it is very important that you add to your question what version of Ubuntu you are using and what version of the Nvidia proprietary driver did you end up installing. With that we can start working on a solution. Also if you happen to look into the last lines that the dmesg command shows, it might also help with the debugging of the problem.

Comment: I can only recommend using the integrated Intel graphics. T530 runs fine with that.

Comment: @LiveWireBT - Yes I also recommend the same assuming he has that option in the BIOS settings (I am guessing) but the problem is still there. Anyway did a bit of searching in the nouveau site and it shows full support for several Quadro video cards: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames It may be limited to having the dual video card but we need more information to study the problem better.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Thank you for your comments. I added the info here. About the `dmesg` lines, are they relevant for the fact that Compiz is not working? I ask because I am not looking to debug the crashes in this question.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I will try it but for now I would just like to make Compiz work with the proprietary drivers. Nonetheless, do you have a link to some guide for using the integrated Intel graphics?